# can someone correct this rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

can someone provide me the correct rewriterule for this? I'm currently stock on this for hours now. 
what i'm trying to do is this.

```
http://example.com/user/blitzen12 
http://example.com/user
```

however when I try to access http://example.com/user it displays the same page as http://example.com/user/blitzen12

this is my rewriterule:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /example.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^agents/([^\/]*)\/?$ user/user-page.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^agents/$ user/index.php [L]
```

Thanks.

This should be the result

```
http://example.com/user/blitzen12  -> http://example.com/user/user-page.php?name=blitzen12
http://example.com/user  -> http://example.com/user/index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just answer my own question in case someone encounter this kind of problem.

After searching on the net for a while now and after trying different options I finally able to get it.

full .htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /zenithrealestate/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^properties/([^/.]+)/?$ properties/property-page.php?pid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^agents/([^/.]+)/?$ agents/agent-page.php?name=$1 [L]
```